# Catch mouse events with CGEvent.tapCreate in Swift on MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cgeventtap

I am novice Swift coder trying to catch mouse events as well as keyboard events.  It seems I am only doing the latter.  The main goal is to allow for «tap-to-click» with Magic Mouse 2 and avoid its loud clicking sound.

Fully working sample at
https://github.com/creasty/Keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/AppDelegate.swift

```
let eventMask = 
    (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | 
    (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue) | 
    (1 << CGEventType.leftMouseDown.rawValue) | 
    (1 << CGEventType.leftMouseUp.rawValue)

guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
    tap: .cghidEventTap,
    place: .headInsertEventTap,
    options: .defaultTap,
    eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
    callback: appComponent.eventTapCallback,
    userInfo: nil
) else {
    fatalError("Failed to create event tap")
}
```

Keyboard presses are caught alright, but no reaction to mouse clicks. Please advise.  Thanks.

Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507) on MacOS 11.5.2

Comment: Where are you writing code?  Start with the class name if you are going to post code.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: The github code does not tap mouse events. Post a [mre] in the question please, including `eventTapCallback`. Why do you want to catch mouse-down events if you don't want to click?

Comment: I want mouse "tap" gestures to be caught and converted to mouse "clicks". The term "tap" has two meanings here: EventTap (the technology) and the tap finger movement (slight touch on mouse without full depress).

Comment: Have you tried `NSEvent.EventTypeMask.any`?

Comment: Thanks @Willeke, I´ve tried `let eventMask = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.any.rawValue` but it does still not react to mouse events.

Comment: Which mouse events? I tried your code, added `leftMouseDown`, and it works for me.

Comment: I must be missing something.  I too added `CGEventType.leftMouseDown.rawValue`to the eventMask and a breakpoint at `func handle`which only triggers on key press, not mouse click.

Comment: `func handle`? Have you tried a break on `appComponent.eventTapCallback`?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks I missed that part! Working now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful feedback from @Willeke and others, we arrived at the following solution:

```
diff --git a/keyboard/AppComponent.swift b/keyboard/AppComponent.swift
index 961a81b..abb2f63 100644
--- a/keyboard/AppComponent.swift
+++ b/keyboard/AppComponent.swift
@@ -20,6 +20,8 @@ final class AppComponent {
             if let manager = _eventManager {
                 return manager.handle(proxy: proxy, cgEvent: event)
             }
+        case .leftMouseDown:
+            print("leftMouseDown")
         default:
             break
         }
diff --git a/keyboard/AppDelegate.swift b/keyboard/AppDelegate.swift
index bc39af6..dc16658 100644
--- a/keyboard/AppDelegate.swift
+++ b/keyboard/AppDelegate.swift
@@ -70,8 +70,8 @@ private extension AppDelegate {
     }
 
     func setupEventTap() {
-        let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue)
-
+        let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.leftMouseDown.rawValue)
+        
         guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
             tap: .cghidEventTap,
             place: .headInsertEventTap,
```